# Sitecore DropTree Query

Tags: sitecore-client, sitecore-api

I am using `Sitecore 9`. I am having a problem trying to populate the `droptree` in the template(source).
The template ID for the Apple, Banana and Peach is `{AB86861A-6030-46C5-B394-E8F99E8B87DB}` and the template id for the Apple Skin, Banana Skin,Peach Skin is `{3FFD8425-4652-4BFE-9D8D-5CC1AE2D24A2}`
This is how my Sitecore structure looks like

```
/sitecore/content/Global/My Manager/MyFruits/
```

under Myfruits

- FruitOne

  - Apple

    - Apple Skin
- FruitTwo

  - Banana

    - Banana Skin
- FruitThree

  - Peach

    - Peach Skin

I only want to show Apple Skin, Banana skin and Peach skin in the droptree.

I am able to show all three using a Droplist or Droplink using this query

`query:/sitecore/content/Global/My Manager/MyFruits//*[@@templateid = '{3FFD8425-4652-4BFE-9D8D-5CC1AE2D24A2}']`

If i use the same query for droptree i only get the first one(Apple Skin). I don't get all three.

I have tried using

`query:./ancestor-or-self::*[@@templatename='Fruity']/sitecore/content/Global/My Manager/MyFruits`

it does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OOTB Sitecore will not give you this type of filtering using DropTree. Droptree shows items as a tree view instead of showing them as the dropdown. The user is allowed to select a single item at a time. It shows a complete Sitecore tree if the source is not provided at the time of field declaration or incorrect source path. The source can be XPath Query or GUID and Item Path.

To fix your particular problem we have multiple options -

- Change your field type to Drop link it will show you the complete list as dropdown
- Use the drop tree field which will show you a complete tree node based on your source but add custom validation for the required template type item. using this, you will not be able to select another item in the list.
- Create a custom field type based on your requirement
- Use multiroot treelist or treelist field and add custom validation of one item-only selection.

There could be some better approaches to fix this issue from different people here, but this is what I am thinking

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `TreeList` instead of `DropTree` due to limited options. The `TreeList` allows users to select descendants of the home item that are based on either the data template named Section or the data template named Page:

```
DataSource=/Sitecore/Content/Home&IncludeTemplatesForSelection=section,page
```

For your requirement, you can use the following options of `TreeList`.

**IncludeTemplatesForDisplay**: Users can only navigate items based on this comma-separated list of data template names and IDs.

**IncludeTemplatesForSelection**: Users can only select items based on this comma-separated list of data template names.

To use other options, you can refer to this article.

https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/90/sitecore-experience-manager/controlling-the-list-of-items-in-a-selection-field.html